# Nested Query .Net Core

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to get employee list who is not a reviwee.

This is employee entity

```
public class Employee: BaseEntity
    {
        public readonly object DepartmentName;

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        
    }
```

This is Reviwee entity

```
public class Reviwee : BaseEntity
    {     
        public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeFirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
        
    }
```

This is BaseEntity

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the method I have wrote

```
public async Task<List<EmployeeDto>> GetEmployeeListAsync()
        {
            var employeeList = await _context.Employees.Where( x=> x.Id != _context.Reviwees.Select(x => x.EmployeeId))
                .Select(x => new EmployeeDto
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    FirstName = x.FirstName
                })
                .ToListAsync();

            return employeeList;
        }
```

The above method is wrong.

Comment: Which type has `_context.Employees`? Why it returns `Reviwee`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the model is made on this way,
`Employee` and `Reviwee` have the same inheritance and `Reviwee` is just an `Employee` with specific characteristic so you can add a boolean property `IsReviwee`

```
public class Employee: BaseEntity
{
    public readonly object DepartmentName;

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsReviwee { get; set; }
    
}
```

the query could be

```
public async Task<List<EmployeeDto>> GetEmployeeListAsync()
    {
        var employeeList = await _context.Employees.Where( x=> x.IsReviwee ==false).ToListAsync();

        return employeeList;
    }
```

If you can't modify entity
try to do this but pay attention, `Reviwee` don't need field `EmployeeId` because inherits `Id` from `BaseEntity`.

```
var query =    
from e in _context.Employee
where !(from o in _context.Reviwee 
        select o.Id)    
       .Contains(e.Id)    
select e;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also your boolean property idea.

Comment: I hope it was useful